# Two-step verification for microsoft company account?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-devops, windows-live

I have a MS company account using Office 365 (so myname@mydomain.com is my account), and I use Office, Azure, and Visual Studio Team Services.

However, I cannot find anywhere how to enable 2FA for this account. I can set up 2FA for my normal, personal, windows live Id using this page:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/two-step-verification-faq.

But that doesnt work for company accounts.

Anyone knows if this is possible? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Multi-Factor Authentication for Azure Active Directory. It is part of [AAD Premium features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn532272.aspx).
You can read how to [enable and configure it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn249466.aspx). And more info on it [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/02/11/mfa-for-office-365-and-mfa-for-azure.aspx).

UPDATE

As per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn532272.aspx):

> Multi-Factor Authentication is now included with Premium and can help
>   you to secure access to on-premises applications (VPN, RADIUS, etc.),

As well as per [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn249466.aspx):

> Azure Multi Factor Authentication is included in Azure Active
>   Directory Premium and as a result it is also included with the
>   Enterprise Mobility Suite

**Note:** MFA is (at least was) possible with the free AAD but only for the Global Admins in the directory, or for Subscription Administrators within an Azure Subscription.

Comment: According to the MS guy who answered [my forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/043f644d-f582-4156-8418-a421d8f2be5c/who-are-administrators-of-an-azure-subscription-for-mfa-purposes?forum=windowsazureactiveauthentication) MFA is free for all AAD admin roles, not just Global Admins.

Comment: I have some more information available in a blog post I published last month:  http://www.edsquared.com/2015/01/17/Securing+Your+Visual+Studio+Online+Account+With+MultiFactor+Authentication.aspx